# Declare user-defined reduction of OpenMP for class template

Tags: c++, templates, openmp

When using OpenMP, I would like to declare an user-defined reduction for a class template.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
  public:
  T Data_;

  template<typename U> friend Foo<U> operator+( const Foo<U>& lhs, const Foo<U>& rhs );
};

template<typename U>
Foo<U> operator+( const Foo<U>& lhs, const Foo<U>& rhs )
{
  Foo<U> Addition;

  Addition.Data_ = lhs.Data_ + rhs.Data_;

  return Addition;
}

#pragma omp declare reduction( + : template<typename U> Foo<U> : omp_out = omp_out + omp_in ) initializer (omp_priv=omp_orig)

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Foo<int> Array[100];
  
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i )
  {
    Array[i].Data_ = i;
  }
  
  Foo<int> Sum {0};
  
  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) reduction( + : Sum )
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i )
  {
    Sum.Data_ += Array[i].Data_;
  }
  
  std::cout << Sum.Data_ << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

But I got the following errors:

```
error: expected type-specifier before 'template'
#pragma omp declare reduction( + : template<typename U> Foo<U> : omp_out = omp_out + omp_in ) initializer (omp_priv=omp_orig)
                                   ^~~~~~~~
```

I can fix the error by replacing `template<typename U> Foo<U>` with `Foo<int>`.

But I would like to know is there any solution by keeping using `template`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have a templated function

```
template<typename T>
T f(T x,T y) {};
```

you can templatize the reduction:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction                                   \
  (rwzt:T:omp_out=f<T>(omp_out,omp_in))
```

And use that as:

```
template<typename T>
T generic_reduction( const vector<T>& tdata ) {
  #pragma omp declare reduction                                   \
    (rwzt:T:omp_out=f<T>(omp_out,omp_in))

  T tmin;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(rwzt:tmin)
   for ( stuff ) {}
  return tmin;
}

auto tm = generic_reduction<float>( /* some vector<float> */ );
```

I'm somewhat bothered by the fact that this needs to define a named function to contain them the reduction, rather than having all code inlined. I can not figure out a way to do this with a lambda in the calling environment.

Comment: Good. This seems to be well supported by mainstream compilers. Just a minor remark: I think it is better to use `const vector<T>&` instead of `vector<T>` to avoid unneeded copies.

Comment: @JérômeRichard With vectors of a size worth parallelizing you're absolutely right. Code edited.